# xproc: p:xquery with multiple input documents

Tags: xquery, xproc

According to [XProc: W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#c.xquery) p:xquery gets only one input document and parameters (which can only be atomic, right?)

```
<p:declare-step type="p:xquery">
 <p:input port="source" sequence="true" primary="true"/>
 <p:input port="query"/>
 <p:input port="parameters" kind="parameter"/>
 <p:output port="result" sequence="true"/>
</p:declare-step>
```

If my query has multiple input documents (from previous steps), do I really have to store them first and load them inside the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the syntax description you quote makes clear, the 'source' port has `sequence="true"`, which means that the step may receive a sequence of documents on the source port, not just one.

So no, you do not really have to store them and then load them inside the query; just feed them into the p:xquery step's source port as a sequence of documents.

Comment: you're right. but its important to know, that the documents are treated differently. the first is the context item, the others are accessed using collection().